# Hover effect over a list of links

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of items that will scroll up or down with a jcarousel whenever I hover the arrows. The list of items has links that need to be linked.

[image: My list of items]

This is what I want to achieve: I need to extend the hover area of the arrows so that the list will scroll as soon as the cursor is in the colored area. I achieve this easily just changing the size of the arrows (they are absolute positioned) and having them on top of the list but my problem is that I can't get my links to work because the arrows containers are just on top of them.

[image: the hover areas]

Edit: I was going to make a fiddle but it didn't seem to work with jcarousel. This is what I have so far:

[Link to website](http://gestyre.com/new)

Comment: please show code or link

Comment: Its very easy to do that but please provide your code as NullPointer said..

Comment: @Elaine Marley see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed the problem is that the overlapping element is *eating* the mouse events and so the actual list items cannot be hovered/clicked etc..

You could use `mouseover` on the container of the list elements and check if the mouse is at the top or bottom half of it..

My working test is

```
var state = '';
$('div.listaterm').mousemove(function(e){
    var self = $(this),
        position = self.offset(),
        height = self.outerHeight(),
        mouse = e.pageY-position.top,
        inTopHalf = mouse <= (height/2),
        sign = inTopHalf ? '-' : '+';

    if (sign != state){
        state = sign;
        jQuery('.jcarouselcall').jcarouselAutoscroll('stop');
        jQuery('.jcarouselcall').jcarouselAutoscroll({'target': sign+'=1'});
        jQuery('.jcarouselcall').jcarouselAutoscroll('start');
    }
}).mouseout(function(e){
    if (!$(this).find(e.relatedTarget).length && !(e.relatedTarget == this)){
        state='';
        jQuery('.jcarouselcall').jcarouselAutoscroll('stop');
    }
});
```

But you need to make the arrow elements not overlap the `div.listaterm` element. And of course remove the hover handlers from the arrows as well..

Comment: Yep, that worked fantastic, and the solution is pretty clever actually, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

your html code of plugin should be like below

```
<a href="#" class="startscroll"><img style="margin-top:60px" src="http://gestyre.com/new/wp-content/themes/gestyre/images/down.png" alt="arriba"></a>

<a href="#" class="stopscroll"><img alt="arriba" src="http://gestyre.com/new/wp-content/themes/gestyre/images/up.png"></a>
```

Css:

you should add the css in your stylesheet

```
.startscroll img
{
   margin-top:60px; // it shifting the down arrow image to the border side
}
```

line 213  : http://gestyre.com/new/wp-content/themes/gestyre/css/app.css

```
.startscroll, .stopscroll {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 157px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

see below image in which i created the border with red color for demo using fire bug after applying the above css.

[image]

Comment: The problem is not about positioning the arrows, but about their functionality conflicting with the ability to click links on the list